# Symfony2 translation of validation messages issue

Tags: php, validation, symfony, internationalization

I have a common problem with translating validator messages in Symfony, and all suggested solutions do not help me.
This is my constraint:

```
//  src/AppBundle/Entity/Friend.php   
/**
         * @var string
         *
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "test")
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $name;
```

And file with translations:

```
// src/AppBundle/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml
test: my message
```

The same file with translations i've also added in app directory. Actually, it doesn't work. What am i missing?

Comment: have you turned on the translation system on Symfony?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you follow this steps, it should work:

First, turn on translation system:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator: { fallback: en }
```

Create the constraint as you did:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Friend.php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;// Don't forget this part.

class Friend
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "test")
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $name;
}
```

Create a translation file under the validators catalog for the constraint messages, typically in the Resources/translations/ directory of the bundle as you did.

```
# validators.en.yml
test: my message
```

**IMPORTANT** Last, clear your cache as you've added new translations (do it even if you're in dev environment).

```
$ php app/console cache:clear
```

For me this solution works.

Comment: Thank you a lot, @acontell. I don't use to **clear cache** usually, because it is not neccessary while working in **dev** mode. You've saved my time

Comment: @Jay yep, happens to me all the time. I've updated the answer giving more importance to that part as it is bound to happen to more people.

Comment: Thanks @acontell your 3 years older answer saved me !

Comment: Thanks @acontell your 3 years older answer saved me ! Your answer should be accepted by Jay